# Check if post value is zero or one

Tags: php

How can i check if a post value is 0 or 1 ?

```
 if($_POST['value'] > '2' OR $_POST['value'] < '0') {
```

If the post value is not 0 or 1 i want to show an error.

is this the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Mar

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to be explicit in what you accept:

```
if ($_POST['value'] === '0' || $_POST['value'] === '1') {
```

This to exclude possible confusion: is 'A' > '1'? That's not very obvious, so it's best to avoid complexities like that and write exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes. But for the error handling i want to check if the input is not zero or not 1.

Can i use this?

if (!$_POST['value'] === '0' || !$_POST['value'] === '1') {

Comment: it's not working. i can input 114 and i dont get an error.

Comment: For the `!$... === '0' || !$... === '1'`: be careful: does the `!` apply to the `$...` or to the `$... === '0'`? Best to be explicit with parenthesis (or move the `!` to the outside: `(!($... === '0' || $... === '1'))`

Comment: @user3374858 why you should you use ! (NOT) if you want to check the input is 0 or 1? you can if 0 or 1else //not 0 nor 1.

Comment: @user3374858 Why would you get an error?  You have to generate the error with your code if the condition is not true.

Comment: @Jerson i want to show an error if the input isn't correct. And the input has to be 0 or 1.

Comment: i tried this:

if (!$_POST['value'] === '0' || $_POST['value'] === '1') { 
   echo'This is not correct'; 
}  

and this
if (!$_POST['value'] === '0' || !$_POST['value'] === '1') { 
   echo'This is not correct'; 
}  

But still i can input other amounts or text.

Comment: === is type safety operator, you can use ==

Comment: @Jerson when i use this output says always This is not correct. When i use 0,1 or 54